# how to install flash player on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: flash

I want to install flash player on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
how i perform it kindly concern with your best

Answer (score 0):

1.Enable ubuntu canonical partners repo

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

2.Update the repos :

```
$ sudo apt update
```

3.Install flash plugin

```
$ sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
```

Exit the Terminal.

IF browser is open, restart it. and navigate to the adobe site ->>
[Adobe flash player](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)

Check whether plugin is installed.

Run the adobe flash link, a prompt will be shown, click on allow and flash content will work :)

Thanks!